# Undefined variable Wp-postratings

Tags: wordpress

Soy nuevo por aquí y tengo una pregunta, ojalá puedan ayudarme.
Recibido este error del plugin de WordPress wp-postratings

Notice: Undefined variable: thumbnail in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/wp-postratings/wp-postratings.php on line 1176

Este es el archivo en conflicto: https://pastebin.com/drFAehgd

Comment: según el autor hay un parche por ahi https://wordpress.org/support/topic/undefined-variable-thumbnail-in-wp-postratings-php-on-line-1176/

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, Pura Vida!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A no ser que veas un error o problema en la funcionalidad del plugin, deberías ignorar este mensaje, que no es un error, sino un "aviso" o "Notice".

Para que estos mensajes no se muestren en tu página web en producción, deberías deshabilitar el modo debug de WordPress y que PHP muestre errores en página:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
ini_set( 'display_errors', false );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Víctor, Pura Vida!

Comment: De nada ;) No te olvides de puntuar o aceptar. Saludos